# exponential function and hyperbolic function inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

I try to solve the following inequality: Let $a>0$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$, and   $t\geq 0$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
e^{\frac{-at}{2}}*\frac{\sinh(\frac{t\Delta}{2})}{\Delta}\leq Ce^{\frac{-t\cdot b^2}{a}}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\frac{a}{2}\leq \Delta\leq a \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \Delta=\sqrt{a^2-4b^2} 
\end{equation}